# How group the employees in ranges of hours?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, group-by

I have this table to save the time the employees spend doing a routine task.

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(100),
   date_task date,
   time_ini time,
   time_end time
);
```

- I'm trying to group the employees who have at least two time_ini's with a difference < 15 minutes with any employee's time_ini or time_end.
- If none of their time_inis meet this condition, then this employee would be grouped alone.
- The groups will be numbered from 1 to n.
- And then the groups will be ordered by date ascending, and time_ini ascending.

This is an example of data:

```
(1,  "oscar", '2012-01-01', '01:30', '01:32'),
(2,  "oscar", '2012-01-01', '02:30', '02:32'),
(3,  "oscar", '2012-01-01', '05:30', '05:32'),
(4,  "oscar", '2012-01-01', '06:30', '06:32'),

(5,  "mario", '2012-01-01', '02:43', '02:43'),
(6,  "mario", '2012-01-01', '02:53', '02:53'),
(7,  "mario", '2012-01-01', '05:30', '05:30'),

(8, "martah", '2012-01-01', '01:25', '01:28'),
(9, "martah", '2012-01-01', '02:29', '02:41'),

(10, "jesus", '2012-01-01', '01:25', '01:28'),
(11, "jesus", '2012-01-01', '01:25', '02:28'),
(12, "jesus", '2012-01-01', '07:33', '08:32'),
(13, "jesus", '2012-01-01', '07:35', '07:36'),
(14, "jesus", '2012-01-01', '08:36', '08:39'),

(15, "rober", '2012-01-01', '02:43', '02:46'),
(16, "rober", '2012-01-01', '02:56', '03:00'),
(17, "rober", '2012-01-01', '02:29', '11:32'),

(18, "pedro", '2012-01-01', '11:36', '12:46'),
(19, "pedro", '2012-01-01', '12:36', '16:46');
```

This would be the result:

```
GROUP       NAME
1           oscar
1           marta
1           jesus
2           mario     
2           rober
3           pedro
```

I came up with something like this:

```
select distinct a.name 
from tasks a
where 
    (select count(id) 
    from tasks b 
    where (
          MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(a.time_ini, b.time_ini)) < 15 OR 
          MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(a.time_end, b.time_ini)) < 15
     ) and
    b.name <> a.name) >= 2;
```

I'm afraid I can't group them this way, but I think I'm not too far to the solution, isn't it?

Any idea, tip or advice will be appreciated, and if you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post. Is little bit hard to explain...

Comment: Is it always the case that a.date_end - a.date_ini < 30 minutes? And I note that date_end is not always > date_ini !?! Oh, and can tasks overlap dates?

Comment: The difference between time_end and time_ini won't be always 30 mins. I built this data only for the example. And time_end must be >= time_ini, sorry, I've edited the post. And tasks can't overlap dates. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: So, if I've got this right then really you're interested in any time_ini that occurs "BETWEEN x.time_ini - 15 INTERVAL 15 MINUTE AND x.time_end + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE", right?

Comment: Nop, I trying to group using the next condition: (a.time_ini between b.time_ini + - 15 mins) OR (a.time_ini between b.time_end + - 15 mins). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (although its not in the format you need it.. it should do the job):

```
SELECT
    a.id as groupId,
    a.name as first,
    b.name as second,
    COUNT(*) as occ
FROM 
    tasks a,task b
WHERE
    b.name <> a.name
    AND a.id > b.id
    AND (
        MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(a.date_ini, b.date_ini)) < 15 OR 
        MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(a.date_end, b.date_ini)) < 15
    )
GROUP BY
    groupId,
    first,
    second
```

**BTW** `jesus` should be in the group with `oscar` and `martha` due to records 10 and 11

Comment: Thanks! It works, but could you try to generate the output with the format I'm trying to get, please? This is my main problem.